# Nodejs ES6 class not returning methods

Tags: node.js, class, ecmascript-6, promise

I am trying to use `ES6 Classes` to construct an error handler in a project I'm working on. After I instantiate the class I try and log the object that is created, hoping to see the two methods I defined `constructMessage` and `handle`, but all I get is the object generated by the constructor function.

Any ideas why this could be happening?

```
'use strict';

const snsHandler = require('./../sns/sns-handler');// snsHandler returns a promise

class ErrorHandler {
  constructor (errObject, snsTopic, snsSubject) {
    this.funcName = errObject.functionName;
    this.errMsg = errObject.errorMessage;
    this.statusCode = errObject.statusCode;
    this.intError = errObject.internalError;
    this.subject = snsSubject;
    this.topic = snsTopic;
  }

  constructMessage () {
    let errorObject = {
      "message": this.errMsg,
      "statusCode": this.statusCode,
      "functionName": this.funcName,
      "internalError": this.intError
    }
    errorObject = JSON.stringify(errorObject);
    return errorObject;
  }

  handle () {
    return snsHandler.manageSns(this.topic, this.constructMessage(), this.subject); // snsHandler returns a promise
  }
}

module.exports = ErrorHandler;
```

Then in another file I require it and instantiate it:

```
'use strict';

const errHandler = require('./lib/modules/errorHandler/error-handler');
const topicName = 'topic';
const snsSubject = 'Error topic';

const simulatePurchase = () => {
  const _err = new errHandler({}, topicName, snsSubject);
  console.log(_err); // ErrorHandler {
                     //  funcName: undefined,
                     //  errMsg: undefined,
                     //  statusCode: undefined,
                     //  intError: undefined,
                     //  subject: 'Error topic',
                     //  topic: 'topic' }
}
```

Comment: `constructMessage` is on the prototype, and will not be displayed by `console.log`. Try logging `_err.constructMessage`.

Comment: thanks. that did do the trick. there is something wrong with the promise being returned by the handle method

Comment: You cannot pass `this.constructMessage` like that. That is basic. You have to pass `() => this.constructMessage()`.

Comment: @torazaburo Nah, that seems to be fine here, it doesn't look like `manageSns` takes a callback there